# how to send email as an alias using googleapis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-api, gmail, alias

I am trying to send mails using googleapis. I need to send mail with alias Name, when i send manually the alias name is showing up. But when trying from API, it shows the old default name.

[I am referring this users.messages.send from this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

```
//gmail object from googleapis library from nodejs
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: auth });
  
//get Alias Name that is configured
  const alias = (await gmail.users.settings.sendAs.list({ userId: userId }))
    .data.sendAs[0].displayName;


const makeBody = (params) => {
  params.subject = new Buffer.from(params.subject).toString("base64");
  const str = [
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\n',
    "MINE-Version: 1.0\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
    `to: ${params.to} \n`,
    `from: ${params.from} \n`,
    `subject: =?UTF-8?B?${params.subject}?= \n\n`,
    `<html><head><style>${params.style}</style></head><body>`,
    params.message,
    `</body></html>`,
  ].join(""); // <--- Modified
  return new Buffer.from(str)
    .toString("base64")
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_");
};

  const raw = makeBody({
    to: userEmail,
    from: alias,
    subject: "some subject",
    message: some message body, --> (html body)
    style, --> (html style attributes)
  });

  gmail.users.messages.send(
    {
      userId: userId,
      resource: {
        raw: raw,
      },
    },
    (err, res) => {
      // Modified
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  );
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code